# Debugging Supercollider OSCresponderNode

Tags: opensoundcontrol, supercollider

Anyone have an idea how to debug supercollider's OSCresponderNode?

I'm trying to catch messages from another program with this :

```
o = OSCresponderNode(nil, '/note', { arg t, r, msg; t.postln; r.postln; msg.postln; Synth( "guru2", [\mfreq, msg[1]]);  }).add;
```

However, when I fire messages at it, supercollider is just giving me

```
FAILURE /note Command not found
```

I'm assuming this is telling me that the supercollider server is successfully picking up a message to address /note, but that either a) the OSCresponderNode wasn't registered correctly, or b) the responder function has failed in some-way.

Am I right in assuming this?

Could it be a failure in defining the node? I don't get an error message when I execute that line. But maybe the callback function doesn't get executed and tested until it's actually triggered?

Answer (score 3):

"FAILURE /note Command not found" is what happens when you send the **server** a message that it doesn't understand. But OSCresponderNode is not a **server**-side object, it's client-side.

What you do to fix this, is send messages to the client's port, not the server's port.

Comment: but how do i find the client port?

Answer (score 0):

Belated response, I'm afraid. But I can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps you could share the code you use to *send* the OSC messages?

Using the code from the Supercollider OSCResponderNode example, I get the following appearing in my post window:

```
133867.10639964
an OSCresponderNode
[ /note, Hello App 1 ]
```

That is, the `t, r, msg` parameters from your OSCResponderNode handler, as expected.